# Uncaught ReferenceError function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a onkey on a input but it won't find the function I have in my js file. I searched through some questions on here but can't find the solution for it.

My input code:

```
<input id="Name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" onkeyup="autocomplet()">
                                    <ul id="Name_list_id"></ul>
```

jQuery:

```
function autocomplet() {
        var min_length = 0;
        var keyword = $('#Name').val();
        if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {keyword:keyword},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#Name_list_id').show();
                    $('#Name_list_id').html(data);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#Name_list_id').hide();
            }
        }


        function set_item(item) {
        $('#Name').val(item);
        $('#Name_list_id').hide();
            }
```

JS files of tutorial:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js">
</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

and on my website:

```
<script src="s/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/events.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: please expand your question to get better help..

Comment: you might have defining functions inside `window.onload`..

Comment: I keep getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomplet is not defined(index):80 onkeyup

Comment: @liquidflo where is your function defined..separate js file?

Comment: No, in my events.js where I have all my functions in but for some reason it won't find this function the others are working

Comment: Is the function defined inside a closure?

Comment: After that I close my $(document).ready(function() { that I have on the top with }); I had a function that I tried before this that was working perfectly but this one isn't working for some reaso. I'm very new to jQuery sorry

Comment: In the tutorial you have this at the top: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> and in my file: <script src="s/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
         <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="js/events.js"></script>
         <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: A better method is to get rid of `onkeyup="autocomplet()"` and replace the `function autocomplet() {` with `$('#Name').on('keyup', function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://vilaskumkar.github.io/test.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>- jsFiddle demo by vilaskumkar</title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/events.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- Add all you JS File in head -->
  <!-- <link href="/css/result-light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
</head>

<body>


  <form>
    <input class="form-control" id="Name" name="name" onkeyup=
    "autocomplet()" type="text">
  </form>

  <ul id="Name_list_id"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting this again JQUERY4U is not defined is it because of my js files? at the comments you can see my js files I have.

Comment: @liquidflo I would recommend you to show us your code in jsfiddle, It'll help us to find out the exact problem.

Comment: I've updated my post I think the problem is with my js files I'm not sure

Comment: @liquidflo Could you please update you html markup like this one, you can view the same code in action at http://vilaskumkar.github.io/test.html

Comment: That worked but can't I have that in my events.js file?

Comment: @liquidflo Could you please check again the same link

Comment: @liquidflo I saw you've aceept the answer, If you find it works fine you can upvote it too ;)